# Implementing MERGE INTO using Table as target and dataframe as source(SPARK/SCALA)

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to implement merge in scala /spark . My target database is DB2.

Spark version : 3.x

if anyone has implemented solution like this please share your thought process

Thanks in advance

Update : As asked by one of the member What do I mean by merge

Table : emp (target) emp_id(primary key) emp_name salary

100 Bob 1000

200 Kelley 2000

300 Ron 1200

Table : emp_ext (source table from where we load data)
emp_id(primary key) emp_name salary

100 Bob 1100 (Row Changed)

200 Kelley 2000 (No Change)

300 Ron 1200 (No Change)

## Final state of table emp

emp_id(primary key) emp_name salary

100 Bob 1100

200 Kelley 2000

300 Ron 1200

Comment: Why do you want to use Spark for such a simple case? Why not just merge the data in SQL?

Comment: Thanks @DinoPrašo, i tried with sql and it worked.